# Azure media service : How to get sts

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, adal, azure-media-services

I used Azure Media Service to import, encode and define key license delivery from the portal.

I am building an app and I would like to know how to get the license. I I don't understand how to build a token with a verification key given the fact that I don't know how to get it from the app.

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked into the discussions in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-cenc-with-multidrm-access-control? If that doesn't help, please contact us via amshelp@microsoft.com so we can review your scenario and provide support. Thanks

Comment: @AnilMurching Is there a document available on how we can write our own STS? The article you just mentioned clearly state that we can write one for license acquisition request.